# Clipping mask problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, mask

I have an image and a compound path.
I want to create a clipping mask for this group of objects in Illustrator.
But I'm facing this problem:

[image]

[image]
(random image for this post)

Where is the problem? 
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm guessing the compound path is your problem. If you give your compound path a fill before creating the clipping mask what does it look like?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The compound path is the problem. Maybe the anchors? [image](http://i.imgur.com/Gt7yCmQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your compound path. If you want to use the whole template as a clipping mask you need one continuous closed shape, what you currently have is a number of different (possibly open) paths.

If your paths are open select overlapping or adjacent end points and use the join command (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) until you have a closed single path. If the paths are closed you can either edit the existing paths or draw new shapes to fill the gaps and use Parhfinder's Unite command to create a single shape. Or a combination of both. Basically just create one single path.

If you don't need the clipping path to be exact (say you need a 3mm bleed around the template you have) just draw a new single path around the existing template.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for your kind help!